# Tinymce toolbar in php twig

Tags: php, tinymce, toolbar

I use tinymce in my project, a blog made with slim and twig.
I had no problem to init the default tinymce script but when i add the code plugin in menu items the rest of the menu disappear.
the code that is working is:

```
 <script>tinymce.init({selector: '#content'});</script>
```

and the view is this
[image]

when i change it to this

```
    <script>tinymce.init({
    selector: '#content',
    plugins: ["code"],
    toolbar: ["code"],
    menubar: ["tools"]
    });</script>
```

The code plugin working but the old toolbar disappear

[image]

what i actually want to do is to keep the default toolbar and add at the end the code plugin, not to remove the default toolbar.

Comment: Spyro read the docs: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar. You need to define the toolbar controls (comma separated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten toolbar config. You have to copy all plugins from default config, and append code again into your config.

Comment: thank you, i didn't realized that i override the default config, i thought that i append. chears